# Nginx pattern matching to part of path

Tags: nginx, url-routing, pattern-matching

Here's what I would like to accomplish:

1. All requests to `/api/...` should be directed to a reverse proxy
2. All requests to `/static/...` should be served from `/html/static/pub`
3. All other requests should be served from `/html/app/pub` OR fall back to `/html/app/pub/index.html`

Changing the folder structure of `/html` is not currently an option.

Here's what my location blocks currently look like:

```
root /html/app/pub/;

location /api/ {
  # proxy details...
}

location ~* /static/(.*) {
  try_files /html/static/pub/$1 =404;
}

location / {
  try_files $uri /index.html;
}
```

With this setup, requirements (1) and (3) are fulfilled, but (2) is not. Any request made to any path within `/static` comes back with HTTP 404. There are no errors in the nginx log, the request is just logged as Not Found.

I've tried many different permutations, each of which broke at least one of the requirements; this is the closest I've gotten to what I'm looking for. I have scoured all the articles I could google (90% of which use literally the same example snippets), but I couldn't find a solution to this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The argument of `try_files` is appended to the `root`. Therefore you might consider adding a `root` directive in the static files `location`.

Comment: @PiotrP.Karwasz What should that root directive be? Any what should the `try_files` directive look like then?

Answer (score 2):

Solved:

```
location ~* /static/(.*) {
  root /html/static/pub/;
  try_files /$1 =404;
}
```